# Can I make the weather widget depend on wifi rather than location?

Tags: updates, app-widgets, weather, samsung-galaxy-mega-2

I upgraded from Galaxy Mega to Galaxy S6 Edge +.

The weather widget seems to depend on me turning on 'location' (which I'm guessing is the renaming of GPS). In Mega, I need only Wifi. Now, I have to turn on location.

Is there a way I can still use the weather widget to see temperature without turning location? If not, what can I use to see temperature and time using a widget way without turning on location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Settings`->`Privacy and Security`->`Location`->`Search method`->Select `WiFi and mobile networks`.
It's there, just named differently because you don't need GPS for location and may choose to disable that feature completely.